# I need to load/performance test chat socket using jmeter & redline 13

Tags: websocket, jmeter, load-testing

I need to Load chat a chat socket having thousands of users simultaneously from multiple locations side by side

Anyone know of a tool or toolset which might help me accomplish this, currently, I am using JMeter WebSocket is there any other tool that can be helpful

Answer (score 0):

JMeter allows multiple protocols to test. I think it also supports Websocket. If you don't know where to start, here step by step [guideline](https://ergashevn.blogspot.com/2021/01/load-testing-in-5-minutes.html) for Jmeter.